# Usarsim sends string data

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to implement robot exploration by ROS-Usarsim, the sensor data comes from the Usarsim as a variable length string, How can I receive these data as a double so I can use it for building my map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10635/usarsim-sends-string-data/) by [Sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/853/sara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If its just a mater of converting a `std::string` to a double, it doesn't get easier than using `boost::lexical_cast` as follows

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
...
std::string str; // keep the string here
double result = boost::lexical_cast<double>(str);
```

have fun

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-22**:
You need to parse this data out of the custom USARSIM format.  This would be better asked in a USARSIM forum.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-19**:
You will need to parse that data. There is nothing ROS specific to that.

**Comment by [Sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/853/sara/) on 2011-07-19**:
This is a sample of the string coming from usarsim: data: STA{Time 154829.4375} {FrontSteer 0} {RearSteer 0} {Battery 99999}data: SEN {Type RangeScanner} {Name lms200} {Resolution 0.1744} {FOV 3.1414} {Range 6.76,6.87,7.20,5.31,6.22,7.41,7.59,7.00,6.68,6.58,6.68,7.00,7.59,8.59,10.23,13 - Sara (5 min

**Comment by [Sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/853/sara/) on 2011-07-19**:
when I do the solution above I get this message: message_traits.h:121:34: error: request for member ‘__getMD5Sum’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const double’ Please advise

**Comment by [Sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/853/sara/) on 2011-07-19**:
The problem is that the string coming from usarsim is about 600 character length. Some of them are text and the other are sensor readings.does your solution above solve the problem?

**Comment by [Sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/853/sara/) on 2011-07-19**:
The problem is that the string coming from usarsim is about 600 character length. Some of them are text and the other are sensor readings.does your solution above solve the problem?

**Comment by [Sara](https://answers.ros.org/users/853/sara/) on 2011-07-19**:
Thanks Mak,

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-11-02**:
Hello, Sara, did you manage to correctly process the sensor data and build a map of the environment by using the makokal code.......